# Intent Not working not landing to one.class page Below is the code

Tags: android

```
public class one extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"lastpage",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        sendSms();
    }

    public void sendSms() {
        Intent intent=getIntent();
        String SMS=intent.getStringExtra("Message");
        Intent intent1=getIntent();
        String Contact=intent1.getStringExtra("Number");
        SmsManager manager=SmsManager.getDefault();
        manager.sendTextMessage(Contact, null, SMS, null, null);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SENT", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

public class AlarmReciever extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(context,one.class);
        Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm is scheduled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

In this the Intent is not landing to one.java activity. And If possible please help if can write the sendSms method in Alarm Receiver.java activity

Answer (score 0):

In your `AlarmReceiver` you never actually start the `one` activity. You also never add the extras you intend to pull out of it.

Try this:

```
Intent intent1 = new Intent(context,one.class);
intent1.putExtra("Message", "foo");
intent1.putExtra("Number", 123456789);
startActivity(intent1 );
```

Comment: i am using putExtra from another activity. Will be an error if i do so?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `startActivity(intent1);` in the `onReceive` method

Answer (score 0):

In your AlarmReciever, you missed out to start the called intent. It's an simple issue. Below i have given the corrected code

```js
public class AlarmReciever extends BroadcastReceiver{

 @Override
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  Intent intent1 = new Intent(context,one.class);
        startActivity(intent1);
  Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm is scheduled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

 }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however it shows an error when i am trying to start Intent.

Comment: what if i use context.startActivity(intent1);

Comment: It was something can not resolve the method Android.context.Intent.